# Understanding GCP IAM between multiple projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, roles, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

In my organization, we work with GCP and have multiple projects there. I'm now trying to organize the IAM roles between all the projects and I'm not sure about some of the IAM settings. Are to projects act as completely separate entities with completely different IAM roles/permissions or are there any overlap between them that can lead to that a change in one project might affect another project?

Comment: Are you using GCP Organizations? If not, then projects are completely isolated. If you are review Jen's answer. I will add that roles can be created at the project level (isolated) but also at the organization level, which means inheritance kicks in. However, changes to IAM in one project do not affect other projects except for cross project access. If you change/create a role in Project A, that does not affect roles in Project B. You can have roles with the same name in multiple projects with different permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing roles in one project will not directly change roles set on another project. But there are some things you'll want to consider.

While projects can have their own access control rules, it is possible to [manage access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control) at more than the project level. Here are the four resource points where you can manage access:

> **Organization level**. The organization resource represents your company.
> IAM roles granted at this level are inherited by all resources under
> the organization.

> **Folder level**. Folders can contain projects,
> other folders, or a combination of both. Roles granted at the highest
> folder level will be inherited by projects or other folders that are
> contained in that parent folder.

> **Project level.** Projects represent a
> trust boundary within your company. Services within the same project
> have a default level of trust. For example, App Engine instances can
> access Cloud Storage buckets within the same project. IAM roles
> granted at the project level are inherited by resources within that
> project.

> **Resource level**. In addition to the existing Cloud Storage and
> BigQuery ACL systems, additional resources such as Genomics Datasets,
> Pub/Sub topics, and Compute Engine instances support lower-level roles
> so that you can grant certain users permission to a single resource
> within a project.

Access can be at the individual level, through a service account, or through organization-wide and Google Group membership. That means that when you add or remove someone from the organization or a Google group, you may inadvertently add or remove them from various roles in different projects.

Also, if a member (individual or group) is assigned a role that gives the capability to change IAM roles, then anyone in that member group can modify permissions. They may change rules in ways you don't want.

When in doubt, use [`testPermissions`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions) to verify that roles are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The IAM roles you set in a project won't affect other projects.

Google Cloud resources are organized hierarchically, where the organization node is the root node in the hierarchy, the projects are the children of the organization, and the other resources are descendants of projects. You can set Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies at different levels of the resource hierarchy. Resources inherit the policies of the parent resource. The effective policy for a resource is the union of the policy set at that resource and the policy inherited from its parent.

Please check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control) where you will find a good explanation of the resource hierarchy for access control

I think this diagram can help you to understand better how IAM works:
[image]